# Batch file running extremely slow while using basic commands

Tags: batch-file

I decided to build an informal project of a tic tac toe bot with 3 modes. For some reason, the detection for the bot using `if` is extremely slow.
It can take up to 30 seconds to run this code:
`

```
if %ui1%==X if %ui2%==X if %ui3%==3 set "ui3=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==X if %ui4%==X if %ui7%==7 set "ui7=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui7%==X if %ui8%==X if %ui9%==9 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==X if %ui5%==X if %ui6%==6 set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui3%==X if %ui6%==X if %ui9%==9 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui2%==X if %ui5%==X if %ui8%==8 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui5%==X if %ui2%==X if %ui8%==8 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==X if %ui7%==X if %ui4%==4 set "ui4=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==X if %ui3%==X if %ui2%==4 set "ui2=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui7%==X if %ui9%==X if %ui8%==8 set "ui8=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui2%==X if %ui8%==X if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==X if %ui6%==X if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui3%==X if %ui9%==X if %ui6%==6 set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==X if %ui6%==X if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
rem now, it tries to find any places it can win.
if %ui1%==O if %ui2%==O if %ui3%==3 set "ui3=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==O if %ui4%==O if %ui7%==7 set "ui7=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui7%==O if %ui8%==O if %ui9%==9 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==O if %ui5%==O if %ui6%==6 set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui3%==O if %ui6%==O if %ui9%==9 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui2%==O if %ui5%==O if %ui8%==8 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui5%==O if %ui2%==O if %ui8%==8 set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==O if %ui7%==O if %ui4%==4 set "ui4=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==O if %ui3%==O if %ui2%==4 set "ui2=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui7%==O if %ui9%==O if %ui8%==8 set "ui8=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui2%==O if %ui8%==O if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==O if %ui6%==O if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui3%==O if %ui9%==O if %ui6%==6 set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==O if %ui6%==O if %ui5%==5 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
rem now, if it reaches this part, it will try to make a pattern in which it wins (all places where it can put two together. It doesn't try to win diagonally)
if %ui1%==O if %ui2%==2 if %ui3%==3 set "ui2=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui3%==O if %ui2%==2 if %ui1%==1 set "ui1=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui1%==O if %ui4%==4 if %ui7%==7 set "ui4=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui2%==O if %ui5%==5 if %ui8%==8 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui3%==O if %ui6%==6 if %ui9%==9 set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui5%==O if %ui2%==2 if %ui8%==8 set "ui2=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui7%==O if %ui8%==8 if %ui9%==9 set "ui8=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
if %ui4%==O if %ui5%==5 if %ui6%==6 set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
```

`
I'm so confused why this would take so long. A single line of this takes wayy under a second. Why does it take so long?

Comment: For starters, it's always going to go to `:easymoduleuser` because `&` means "runs this command and then run this other command" and you didn't group the `set` and `goto` properly so the very first `goto :easymoduleuser` will always get triggered.

Comment: Also, it _really_ doesn't help that these checks are both unsorted and ungrouped. If you're looking for socks in your sock drawer and they're all loose, you're going to take way longer to find two that match.

Comment: At a glance, your using far more variables and performing an excessive number of conditional checks for the actual number of X/Y position values you need in a task like this.

Comment: Batch files _batch_ a series of user commands. It is not a programming language. The suitable programming languages built into Windows are VBScript, JScript, C#, and VB.NET. Powershell is a system interpreter like Batch.

Comment: @Mark - it's got `if` and `for` statements. It's close enough.

Comment: can't replicate. Are you positive, it's that code that takes so long?

Comment: [You have duplicated line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euksC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce conditional testing by Tracking the available grid positions in a variable, then use Substring Modification to subtract grid positions from the variable as moves are taken. Track the AI's Succesful moves in another variable, and a List of winning grid moves in a 3rd Pseudo-Array Variable. Use a findstring function within a for loop to test the AI's moves taken against the winning moves array, and increment a value for each match (Resetting to 0 when processing the next element in the array) - If you have two matches, you're one move from a win, and you can test the available grid positions Variable to see if the relevant position is available.

In the same vein, you can track the players moves in the same fashion and allow the AI access to the same check on how close the Player is to winnning so it can Block the players move if no win is available for the AI

Answer (score 0):

What's happened if you apply **`setlocal`** and **`enabledelayedexpansion`**  with this code layout?

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

if /i "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="XX3" ( set "ui3=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="XX7" ( set "ui7=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="XX9" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui5!!ui6!"=="XX6" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="XX9" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui2!!ui5!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui5!!ui2!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui7!!ui4!"=="XX4" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui3!!ui2!"=="XX4" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui7!!ui9!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui2!!ui8!!ui5!"=="XX5" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="XX5" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui3!!ui9!!ui6!"=="XX6" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="XX5" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )

:: now, it tries to find any places it can win.

if /i "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="OO3" ( set "ui3=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="OO7" ( set "ui7=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="OO9" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui5!!ui6!"=="OO6" ( set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="OO9" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui2!!ui5!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui5!!ui2!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui7!!ui4!"=="OO4" ( set "ui4=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui3!!ui2!"=="OO4" ( set "ui2=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui7!!ui9!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui8=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui2!!ui8!!ui5!"=="OO5" ( set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="OO5" ( set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui3!!ui9!!ui6!"=="OO6" ( set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="OO5" ( set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )

:: now, if it reaches this part, it will try to make a pattern
:: in which it wins (all places where it can put two together.
:: It doesn't try to win diagonally)

if /i "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="O23" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui3!!ui2!!ui1!"=="O21" ( set "ui1=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="O47" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui2!!ui5!!ui8!"=="O58" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="O69" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui5!!ui2!!ui8!"=="O28" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="O89" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if /i "!ui4!!ui5!!ui6!"=="O56" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
```

---

> - If yours variable are case-sensitive, remove **`/i`** in: ****`if`** <strike>**`/i`**</strike>**
>
>   ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

if "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="XX3" ( set "ui3=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="XX7" ( set "ui7=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="XX9" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui5!!ui6!"=="XX6" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="XX9" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui2!!ui5!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui5!!ui2!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui7!!ui4!"=="XX4" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui3!!ui2!"=="XX4" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui9!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui2!!ui8!!ui5!"=="XX5" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="XX5" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui9!!ui6!"=="XX6" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="XX5" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )

:: now, it tries to find any places it can win.

if "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="OO3" ( set "ui3=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="OO7" ( set "ui7=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="OO9" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui5!!ui6!"=="OO6" ( set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="OO9" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui2!!ui5!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui5!!ui2!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui9=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui7!!ui4!"=="OO4" ( set "ui4=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui3!!ui2!"=="OO4" ( set "ui2=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui9!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui8=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui2!!ui8!!ui5!"=="OO5" ( set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="OO5" ( set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui9!!ui6!"=="OO6" ( set "ui6=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui6!!ui5!"=="OO5" ( set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser )

:: now, if it reaches this part, it will try to make a pattern
:: in which it wins (all places where it can put two together.
:: It doesn't try to win diagonally)

if "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="O23" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui2!!ui1!"=="O21" ( set "ui1=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="O47" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui2!!ui5!!ui8!"=="O58" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="O69" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui5!!ui2!!ui8!"=="O28" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="O89" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui4!!ui5!!ui6!"=="O56" ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
```

---

---

> - Or ... and I'm not sure if this can be "faster" than the
>     previous code ..:
>
>   ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

if "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="XX3" ( set "ui3=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="XX7" ( set "ui7=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui7!!ui4!"=="XX4" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui3!!ui2!"=="XX4" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui9!!ui8!"=="XX8" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
echo/!ui7!!ui8!!ui9! !ui3!!ui6!!ui9!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "XX9" >nul && set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
echo/!ui2!!ui5!!ui8! !ui5!!ui2!!ui8!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "XX8" >nul && set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
echo/!ui3!!ui9!!ui6! !ui4!!ui5!!ui6!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "XX6" >nul && set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
echo/!ui4!!ui6!!ui5! !ui2!!ui8!!ui5! !ui4!!ui6!!ui5!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "XX5" >nul && ( set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )


:: now, it tries to find any places it can win.
if "!ui1!!ui2!!ui3!"=="OO3" ( set "ui3=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="OO7" ( set "ui7=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui7!!ui4!"=="OO4" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui3!!ui2!"=="OO4" ( set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui9!!ui8!"=="OO8" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
echo=!ui2!!ui8!!ui5! !ui4!!ui6!!ui5! !ui4!!ui6!!ui5!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "OO5" >nul && set "ui5=O" & goto :easymoduleuser
echo=!ui4!!ui5!!ui6! !ui3!!ui9!!ui6!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "OO6" >nul && set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
echo=!ui2!!ui5!!ui8! !ui5!!ui2!!ui8!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "OO8" >nul && set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
echo=!ui7!!ui8!!ui9! !ui3!!ui6!!ui9!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "OO9" >nul && set "ui9=O" && goto :easymoduleuser


:: now, if it reaches this part, it will try to make a pattern
:: in which it wins (all places where it can put two together.
:: It doesn't try to win diagonally)
if "!ui3!!ui2!!ui1!"=="O21" ( set "ui1=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui1!!ui4!!ui7!"=="O47" ( set "ui4=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui3!!ui6!!ui9!"=="O69" ( set "ui6=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
if "!ui7!!ui8!!ui9!"=="O89" ( set "ui8=O" && goto :easymoduleuser )
echo=!ui5!!ui2!!ui8! !ui1!!ui2!!ui3!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe "[O23] [028]" >nul && set "ui2=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
echo=!ui2!!ui5!!ui8! !ui4!!ui5!!ui6!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe "[O58] [O56]" >nul && set "ui5=O" && goto :easymoduleuser
```

---